# How to loop through excel sheets and perform same task on each sheet using python

Tags: python, loops, merge

I have one excel file with many rows of data. I have a second file with multiple sheets. Using python, I want to loop through each sheet on the second file, and merge it with the data on the first file (they have the same column headers).

As a final export, I would like to have all the merged data back on the first file.

I'm relatively new to python and don't have any code written except for reading in the pandas library and the two files.

Comment: Have you tried something so far ? If yes please share it so others can build upon it.

Comment: Please share your example inputs and expected output with the code that you have tried so far!

Comment: So you want to append the data of the second sheet into the first sheet. Am I correct? And do you care about what if there is a duplicate. Also what are the various field names in the sheet, do they have some column like a serial number because that could affect the code that would be written.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `file1.xlsx` is your main file and `file2.xlsx` is your file with the multiple sheets:

```py
import pandas

df_main = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
multiple_sheets = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx', sheet_name=None)  # None means all sheets, this produces a dict of DataFrames with the keys as the sheet names.

for x in multiple_sheets.values():  # Loop through dict with x as the df per sheet
    # Cleanup before adding.
    df_main = pd.concat([df_main, x], ignore_index=True)
```

From there, you can now do your cleanup and save the DataFrame as a new Excel file (i.e., `df_main.to_excel('file1.xlsx')`).

References:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Thank you! This is working however the append is populating an error as it won't work with dictionaries. From what I can tell...

Comment: Oopsie, looks like the result of `multiple_sheets` is a dict, not a list as I initially thought. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.